# PHP / MySQL date minus 20 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to find all entries into the database from 20 seconds ago (message system) - the script is running on ajax so it keeps checking every 10 seconds.

In the database I have everything stored in a VARCHAR section (i know datetime is better, but I don't know how to implement it with the formatting I want - maybe it's easy? I don't know.)

The date in the database looks like this: 2014-04-26 02:45:19 pm

The `$dateToCheck` variable is working fine giving me a time 20seconds ago.

Here's the code:

```
$dateToCheck = date('Y-m-d H:i:s a', time() -20);

$check_Mail_footer = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE `to` = ? AND `deleted` = ? AND `read` = ? AND date > ?");

$check_Mail_footer->execute(array($user_id,0,0,$dateToCheck)); 

$result = $check_Mail_footer->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Error:

```
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
 server version for the right syntax to use near 'date > 
'2014-04-26 14:55:48 pm'' at line 1'
```

Comment: Why are you using this format of date? Timestamp is more flexible. So I recommend to use timestamp in future :)

Comment: I know - I took a shortcut... Might have to change everything ..

Comment: You really should make your time values be ACTUAL time fields in the db, then you could simply have `SELECT ... WHERE timefield <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 20 SECOND)`. Comparing date/time values as a string is a bad idea, ieven if you're lucky enough to have your dates in a most-significant-first formatting.

Comment: what is the data type of date in the table ? varchar ?

Comment: @MarcB you actually helped me - i just added a current timestamp in the mysql -- I didn't want to add more code but this was easy. Thank You .

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty "In the database I have everything stored in a VARCHAR section"

Comment: Since no one else mentioned it, just a sidenote, time is in microseconds, so 20 seconds is really 20*1000. But adding a field was the best option.

Comment: @MarcB

Be safe with this solution. Every action on data (in db) will update new time. It can be unwanted when you want to store for example: insert date etc.

Comment: date stored as varchar are evil and in the query for comparison requires conversion here it might help you in your case http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c18b/7

Comment: I actually keep getting `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as the timestamp ... i set it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ..ideas?

Comment: uh, what microseconds? This is PHP and MySQL. their timestamp resolution is 1 second. If you're storing microsecond-resolution timetamps, then you can't use mysql native types.

Comment: mysql date/time format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. it's a 24hr clock and does NOT have am/pm in it.

Comment: @MarcB but shouldn't mysql insert it for me if i selected CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or should i still insert it?

Comment: @MarcB You're right that was my mistake, I was thinking of sleep (I've used that command more in the last week than I care to discuss) and it uses microseconds...time is indeed seconds, wow I'm tired...

Comment: @davids.1 If you used CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the defined value, you're fine.

Comment: @MarcB see last table like curiosity :)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: @Thomas what do you mean? that I set it as the default.

Comment: First, I used the word time instead of fine lol but if when you made the table, if you set the timestamp field's default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, it will every insert, use the timestamp.

Comment: @jakon: "literal values". there are no native storage types in mysql that support anything other than 1-second resolution time values. you stuff that `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ssssss` value into a timestamp or datetime field, the fraction seconds will be lost.

Comment: Yeah it should insert without me doing anything (i just left a '' in the query) but it keeps inserting zeros.